# HTTP PUT request using a form in angular 2

Tags: angular

My post,get and delete request are working fine but i have been struggling on how to make a put request when i submit my form. I am able to fetch data into the form  alright but when i click the submit button to edit the data , the update does not reflect in the database. Here is my code below

//form to edit

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onEdit(edit)" #edit="ngForm" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="edit.first_name" name="first_name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"  [(ngModel)]="edit.last_name" name="last_name" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Edit</buttton>
```

//component

```
edit = {
        first_name: "",
        last_name: ""
       }

onEdit() {
    this.httpService.update(this.edit)
         .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data)
         )}
```

//edit person according to row index

```
editPerson(person) {
  this.edit = person;
  console.log(person)
}
```

// button to edit

```
  <td><a class="btn btn-default"  data-target="#edit" (click)="editPerson(client)"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>Edit</td>
```

//httpservice

```
update(person) {
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        let body = JSON.stringify(person);
        return this.http.put('http://example.com'+person.id,body,headers)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json());
```

Comment: you will need to add `httpService` class

Comment: @suraj, sorry i forgot to add the service... i actually have that already but it is still not working .  i have edited the question

Comment: hmm.. `'http://example.com'+client.id` I think you are missing a `/` between domain and client id

Comment: also, after body, set options object not headers..

Comment: is there any error occurred in the console? or have you monitor the network in the Developer tool?

Comment: @XinMeng i get this error XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Redirect from 'http://localhost:9000/api/people_api/v1/person/%2083' to 'http://localhost:4200/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

Comment: Besides, i have installed the plugin to solve for CORS issue. But i want to know if my httpservice are correctly done

Comment: If you have correctly configured your CORS filter, it's possible that the browser is not allowing this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: @DanielHigueras, Thanks a lot for much insight. I just download the firefox and the CORS issue doesn't appear. I get a 302 status...

Comment: @Switz So this fixed your issue? Shall I write it as an answer?

Comment: @DanielHigueras, sure ..thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, the problem was using Chrome and localhost together. Chrome has a restriction that doesn't allow CORS requests when using localhost.

For more details see this answer:
[Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)

Comment: try to change your hosts file in windows->system32->driver->etc->hosts and try to add new line  127.0.0.1 mytest.com. and now open your browser with mytest.com

Comment: True, setting an alias in the hosts file can help you with this problem

Answer (score 0):

try to add new line at your hosts file

windows->system32->driver->etc->hosts ( navigation to hosts file)

get your localhost ip by using cmd "ipconfig" command

and than  add new with your localhost ip and dummy url

for example

`127.0.0.1 mytest.com`

and than open your browser with mytest.com